# Apears-to-be-useless guard in do block saves from maximum stack error

Tags: runtime-error, callstack, purescript

Doing exercises from "PureScript by Example" I tryed to do some modifications to the code. I can't understand few things:

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Data.Array ((..),(:))
import Control.MonadZero (guard)

factors n = do
  x <- 1 .. n
  guard $ (n `mod` x) == 0
  pure x

-- WORKS OK
factorizations n = [n] : do
  x <- factors n
  guard $ x > 1 && x < n
  xs <- factorizations $ n / x
  pure $ x : xs

factors' n = do
  x <- 2 .. (n - 1)
  guard $ (n `mod` x) == 0
  pure x

-- ALSO WORKS
factorizations' n = [n] : do
  x <- factors' n
  guard $ x > 1 && x < n -- LOOKS USELESS: x is never 1 or n, so guard never fails
  xs <- factorizations' $ n / x
  pure $ x : xs

-- RUNTIME ERROR: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
-- at ...\node_modules\Data.Array\foreign.js:8:19
factorizations'' n = [n] : do
  x <- factors' n
  -- no guard
  xs <- factorizations'' $ n / x
  pure $ x : xs
```

Why "useless" `guard` saves from runtime error? Is it realy useless in `factorizations''`? Isn't PureScript is designed so that runtime errors are next to imposible?

**EDIT** Ramda.js version doing the same

```
let factors = n => R.filter(i => n%i==0, R.range(1,n+1))

let factorizations = n => [[n], ...R.chain(
  x => R.map(
  xs => [x, ...xs], factorizations(n/x)
))(R.filter(x => x>1&&x<n, factors(n)))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **your guard is not useless, it does its duty**.

---

**First**, notice that `factorizations'` and `factorizations''` don't actually call themselves recursively. Instead, they call `factorizations` (without the prime). I am now going to assume that this is some weird typo in the question, and your actual code is properly recursive.

**Assuming that's the case**, the problem you see happens because `a..b` doesn't do what you think it does.

Try this in your REPL:

```
> 2..1
[2,1]
```

Huh?

This is [by design](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-arrays/blob/1bca4c0b8904e65d356ed6d8db8d6f7e071132d3/src/Data/Array.js#L7): operator `..` will never return an empty array, even if given a "flipped" range. For "flipped" ranges, it will return all the numbers in that range, but sorted backwards.

So this is what happens:

```
1. factorizations'' n=4
  1.a. factors' n=4  =>  [2]
  1.b. n/x = 2
2. factorizations'' n=2
  2.a. factors' n=2  =>  [2]
  2.b. n/x = 1
3. factorizations'' 1
  3.a. factors' n=1  =>  [1]
  3.a. n/x = 1
4. factorizations'' 1
  -- and so on
```

Note that this only works for even `n`. Odd numbers won't have `2` among their factors, which means that `factors'` will never be called with argument `2`.

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you for answering my questions again and again=) Yes, you are right - there is a typo in the question. I also tried to reproduce the code in ramda.js, and it also hit the ceiling with maxed stack.